# Property 'delegate' not found on object

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, delegates

So here's my WSWordlistTableView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface WSWordlistTableView : UITableView {

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <UITableViewDataSource>    datasource;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <UITableViewDelegate>      delegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;

@end
```

As you can see, there are `delegate` and `datasource` properties.

My WSWordlistTableViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "WSWordlistManager.h"
#import "WSUserManager.h"

@interface WSWordlistTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

So, I'm building a sliding drawer view with this table that slides over the main VC. Here is the method in the main VC that creates the view and controller and then slides them onto screen:

```
- (IBAction)slideWordlistView:(id)sender {

    if(!self.wordlistTableView ) {
       CGRect frame = CGRectMake(30, 340, 100, 310);
       self.wordlistTableView = [[WSWordlistTableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    }      
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.wordlistTableView];

    if(!self.wordlistTableViewController) {
       self.wordlistTableViewController = [[WSWordlistTableViewController alloc] init];
    }
    self.wordlistTableViewController.view.frame = self.wordlistTableView.bounds;
    self.wordlistTableViewController.view.autoresizingMask = self.wordlistTableView.autoresizingMask;
    [self addChildViewController:self.wordlistTableViewController];
    [self.wordlistTableView addSubview:self.wordlistTableViewController.view];
    [self.wordlistTableViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];


    // *** THESE LINES THROW THE ERRORS
    self.wordlistTableView.delegate = self.wordlistTableViewController;
    self.wordlistTableView.datasource = self.wordlistTableViewController;


    CGFloat newX = kVisibleX;
    NSLog(@"newX = %f", newX);
    [UIView animateWithDuration: .25
                     animations:
     ^{
         CGRect drawerFrame = self.wordlistTableView.frame;
         drawerFrame.origin.x = newX;
         self.wordlistTableView.frame = drawerFrame;
     }];
```

}

```
self.wordlistTableView.delegate = self.wordlistTableViewController;
self.wordlistTableView.datasource = self.wordlistTableViewController;
```

Those two lines both throw errors saying they can't find the properties 'delegate' nor 'datasource' on 'WSWordlistTableView*'. They're both there. I don't get it.

Comment: Does your WSWordlistTableViewController.m import WSWordlistTableView.h?

Comment: Also, in WSWordlistTableView.h, why did you declare the two properties? Those will be inherited from `UITableView`. Same for the `initWithFrame:` method.

Comment: Also, in WSWordlistTableViewController.h, there is no need to specify that the class conforms to the two protocols. You will get that from `UITableViewController`.

Comment: `WSWordlistTableViewController` doesn't seem to have a property named `wordlistTableView`.

Comment: @rmaddy. So WSWordlistTableViewController.m didn't import WSWordlistTableView.h, and that fixed it. I also cleared out my tableView and tableViewController as you suggested.

Comment: @rmaddy.  I must be a little slow this morning, but why would WSWordlistTableViewController.m have to know about WSWordlistTableView.h in order for me to access the tableView's properties? I'm assuming it has something to do with being a protocol property, but I can't quite complete the logic.

Comment: @SmoothAlmonds Actually, after a closer look, it's the your main VC .m file that needs the import. I though the code you posted was for WSWordlistTableView but now I see it's for your main VC.

Comment: @rdmaddy Well, it was already imported into my main VC when the errors were appearing, and after I imported in my WSWordlistTableViewController I can now access the properties on the tableView! No idea why.

Comment: So that created a `duplicate interface declaration` error because I was importing into both the WSWordlistTableView.h into both the main VC and the tableViewVC. I'm now importing WSWordlistTableView.h into the tableViewVC.h, and then importing the tableViewVC.h into my mainVC.h. Now everything works but I still don't understand why.